# Using C# to execute CMD commands

Tags: c#, command-line, command-prompt

Here's the thing , i have a python interpreter and i want to run sqlmap using cmd with C# . Now the thing is i know how to run a normal cmd command from c# , if i run the following command on cmd

```
python sqlmap.py -u http://www.eastodissa.ac.in/news-and-events.php?id=22 --dbs
```

it asks for some user inputin the form of

```
[y/n]
```

and then it continues processing.

My question is that if i want to automate this process using C# that is bypassing these [y/n]'s with the default value i set and how to check whether the command has been executed or not , how will this be done. I'm kind of new to c#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/16029939/1036187

Comment: Now the thing is how will i know that the process in my case sqlmap is waiting for an input [y/n] ?

Comment: @Harry47 How about to try something and ask a specific question other than *"how can I do it"*

Comment: Giving an answer would have been appreciated @14V

Comment: @Harry47: If you write arguments to your process with StreamWriter, you can read outputs with StreamReader

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do "the pipe trick" to auto insert your answer.

```
|y
```

Comment: Can you like give me an example  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("yourcommandhere");
```